# Approach topological manifolds with smooth manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, compact-manifolds

Because I'm doing some problems that consider all the manifolds while the situation is really clear when considering only smooth manifolds. Thus my question is can we always appoint a topological manifold with a smooth manifold such that they are homotopy equivalent? When M is compact, I think we can embed it into an Euclidean space then maybe we can isotopy it slightly so that it is deformed into a smooth manifold.

Comment: This is not true even if we replace "topological" by piecewise linear! The first counterexample was produced by Kervaire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As surprising as it is, this is not true.

By the work of Freedman, a compact, simply-connected topological 4-manifold is determined up to homeomorphism by the intersection form on second cohomology together with a certain $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ invariant. Moreover, all unimodular intersection forms arise in this way.

By work of Donaldson, the intersection forms that arise from smooth manifolds are rather special. Since the intersection form is a homotopy invariant, it follows that there exist topological 4-manifolds that are not smoothable, even up to homotopy.

You can find more details at [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-manifold).

Comment: Wow, this is really interesting. So there is actually a huge difference between smooth and topological manifolds? I thought they are almost the same before.